# How to match string to array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array that contain strings

`commentArray ={ "words":[ "xyz", "abc", "random", "sample" ] }`

And I want to match string

```
 var comment = "hello world ran"
```

What I'm doing is

```
commentArray.words.find(words => {
    if (comment.toLowerCase().includes(words.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

it giving true because "random" contains "ran" but I want true only if matches whole string not characters.

Comment: Use `===` instead of `.includes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const commentArray = {
    "words": [ "xyz", "abc", "random", "sample" ] 
};

const comment = "hello world ran";
const commentArr = comment.split(' ');

commentArray.words.find(words => {
    if (commentArr.includes(words.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var commentArray ={ "words":[ "xyz", "abc", "random", "sample" ] }

 var comment = "hello world random";
 var commentInWords = comment.split(" ");
 var res = commentArray.words.filter(words => {
    let a = _.includes(commentInWords,words.toLowerCase())
        if (a) {
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
      }
 });

 console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting _ is not defined

Comment: @chetankumar, "_.includes" is a lodash function. you need to import cdn for that. you can get it from this link https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/

Answer (score 1):

```
var commentArray ={ "words":[ "xyz", "abc", "random", "sample" ] };
var comment = "hello xyz";
var commentInWords = comment.split(" ");
 var res = commentArray.words.filter(words => {
   for(var i = 0; i <= commentInWords.length; i++){
    var a = (commentInWords[i] == words.toLowerCase());
        if (a) {
          return true;
        }
   }
 });

 console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Split the string "comment" into array of words

2) For each word from comment, try to find it in you "words" array. You can use something like your comparison but you need to compare with `===` instead of `includes`, of course.

Comment: @chetankumar Did you try this too, as stated by Pac0? : _You can use something like your comparison but you need to compare with === instead of includes, of course._ This just **must** work, because strict equal will never return true with "ran" against "random" and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

commentArray.words.some( word => ~comment.split(" ").indexOf(word))